# Autocomplete Implementation using Database as the source.

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, dojo

I have been trying and searching this for so long, but unable to find the right way of doing this. I have this database from which i want to retrieve some values which will be my auto-complete data source. i have my connection working and i am able to retrieve values in an array which my method is returning. but i am unable to go past this. Please help me out with a jsp page where i can retrieve this array as a json data or can i retrieve this directly and put it in my jsp code as a source for my auto-complete. I can use any framework be it Dojo or J query. Thanks in advance.

populatetextbox.java

```
package classes.web;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PopulateTextbox {

    List <String>rowValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] contactListNames; 
    Connection con=null;
    Statement st=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;

    public String[] method(){


        try{


        String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
        Class.forName(driver);

        String db = "jdbc:odbc:Practice_Database";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(db,"","");

        st = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT Emp_Name FROM EmployeeSearch"; 
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()){

            rowValues.add(rs.getString("Emp_Name"));
        }
        contactListNames = (String[]) rowValues.toArray(new String[rowValues.size()]);

    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    /*finally{
        try {
                if(con!=null)con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
            if(rs!=null)rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }try {
            if(st!=null)st.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }*/
        return contactListNames;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned using JSP, dojo one way to do it is:
1) Include dojo and supporting files in your JSP (in the  section)
2) In your Java code, use a library such as GSon to convert the java array to JSON. (Alternately you can even construct the JSON object as a string when preparing the java array)
3) use the dojo combobox or filteringSelect widget (both support auto-complete) in your JSP:
 in the html body section. For examples, see:
http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/form/FilteringSelect
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/form/_autoComplete.html?testWidget=dijit.form.FilteringSelect
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/form/_autoComplete.html?testWidget=dijit.form.ComboBox

The following answer I provided to another question might help you with details on how to include in JSP:
[Displaying Data on a JSP page using Dojo Data grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453768/displaying-data-on-a-jsp-page-using-dojo-data-grid/9460690#9460690)

Alternately, you can use plain HTML for your presentation layer and use AJAX to obtain the data for your combobox (via a servlet that returns JSON, for example)
I prefer this approach since it keeps the presentation layer completely separate from your middle-tier and backend

You can also use JQuery UI widgets instead of Dojo:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/